# Foreign Keys on Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

Getting this error with the db models. Any idea what could be the problem?

```
InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Stand|stand, expression 'Stand.item_code_name==item_id' failed to locate a name ("name 'item_id' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.Stand'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.


class Stand(db.Model):
    stand_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key = True) 
    stand_name = db.Column(db.String(24), index = True, unique = True)
    item_code_name =db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('item_codes.item_id'))
    item_codes= db.relationship('Item_codes', primaryjoin = "Stand.item_code_name==item_id")  


class Item_codes(db.Model): 
    item_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key = True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = True)
    combi = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

Comment: You have to mention the model as well while declaring the primaryjoin. Try this - `primaryjoin = "Stand.item_code_name==Item_codes.item_id"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapper needs to know which model to join against.

```
class Stand(db.Model):
    stand_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True) 
    stand_name = db.Column(db.String(24), index=True, unique=True)
    item_code_name = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('item_codes.item_id'))
    item_codes = db.relationship('Item_codes', primaryjoin="Stand.item_code_name==Item_codes.item_id")
```

I'd also recommend calling the field `Stand.item_code_id` (or something along those lines). With `_name` I'd expect it to join against `Item_code.item_name`.